# App will launch in simulator and building directly from developer but then will not launch on ad hoc users

Tags: iphone, ios, provisioning

We have an app that will launch in the simulator and for the developer when building the app

However when an ipa of the app and provisioning profle is sent to the adhoc tester it will install but when trying to launch it will instantly "crash".

The ad hoc tester can also run the app via simulator with no problems.

Ad hoc tester has tested on 2 devices (ipad & iphone)
Prior to installation via itunes
 Ad hoc tester has cleaned out all previous app versions on devices
 Ad hoc tester has cleaned out all previous provision profiles

So our question's are
 Has anybody encountered this before?

Attached is a log, is there a way to get a more detailed one for further analysis?

Appreciate any help on this.. thanks!

```
Incident Identifier: F78F7E33-1570-41EC-8F94-D6E9A85B8CBB
CrashReporter Key:   c8a0514bdf8b0b0312bf1a7cf823de54114e0232
Hardware Model:      iPhone1,2
Process:         Atlas [167]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/E7DDCF43-60E3-483D-8CF5-    D7EEA98D1769/Atlas.app/Atlas
Identifier:      Atlas
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-07-30 16:40:03.116 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de3ad0 0x35d5a000 + 563920
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de3abe 0x35d5a000 + 563902
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de3ab2 0x35d5a000 + 563890
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35dfad5e 0x35d5a000 + 658782
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x374f2a00 0x3748d000 + 416256
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32d9d8d8 0x32d95000 + 35032
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x374f0100 0x3748d000 + 405760
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x374f0178 0x3748d000 + 405880
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x374f02a0 0x3748d000 + 406176
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32d9bf28 0x32d95000 + 28456
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3759dabc 0x374f9000 + 674492
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3759daf0 0x374f9000 + 674544
12  UIKit                           0x35b63af8 0x358d3000 + 2689784
13  UIKit                           0x35b65638 0x358d3000 + 2696760
14  UIKit                           0x35a7e3a4 0x358d3000 + 1749924
15  UIKit                           0x35a7d278 0x358d3000 + 1745528
16  UIKit                           0x35926dec 0x358d3000 + 343532
17  Atlas                           0x00002846 -[AtlasAppDelegate   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AtlasAppDelegate.m:21)
18  UIKit                           0x35924fd0 0x358d3000 + 335824
19  UIKit                           0x3591ea70 0x358d3000 + 309872
20  UIKit                           0x358d82dc 0x358d3000 + 21212
21  UIKit                           0x358d7b14 0x358d3000 + 19220
22  UIKit                           0x358d73ac 0x358d3000 + 17324
23  GraphicsServices                0x33e77c80 0x33e72000 + 23680
24  CoreFoundation                  0x3752f5c4 0x374f9000 + 222660
25  CoreFoundation                  0x3752f582 0x374f9000 + 222594
26  CoreFoundation                  0x3752182e 0x374f9000 + 165934
27  CoreFoundation                  0x37521504 0x374f9000 + 165124
28  CoreFoundation                  0x37521412 0x374f9000 + 164882
29  UIKit                           0x3591d54c 0x358d3000 + 304460
30  UIKit                           0x3591a550 0x358d3000 + 292176
31  Atlas                           0x00002752 main (main.m:14)
32  Atlas                           0x000026d0 start + 44

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35d8f974 0x35d5a000 + 219508
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35e5e2fc 0x35d5a000 + 1065724
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35e5dd68 0x35d5a000 + 1064296
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35e5d788 0x35d5a000 + 1062792
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de6970 0x35d5a000 + 575856
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35ddd2fc 0x35d5a000 + 537340

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de72fc 0x35d5a000 + 578300
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de6b50 0x35d5a000 + 576336
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35ddd2fc 0x35d5a000 + 537340

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35d5b3b0 0x35d5a000 + 5040
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35d5d894 0x35d5a000 + 14484
2   CoreFoundation                  0x37521f7c 0x374f9000 + 167804
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37521780 0x374f9000 + 165760
4   CoreFoundation                  0x37521504 0x374f9000 + 165124
5   CoreFoundation                  0x37521412 0x374f9000 + 164882
6   WebCore                         0x3318bd14 0x33070000 + 1162516
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de5b44 0x35d5a000 + 572228
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35dd77a4 0x35d5a000 + 513956

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3e74f308
r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x00142efc      r6: 0x35ce4a24      r7: 0x2fdfdf4c
r8: 0x3eba55a8    r9: 0x0000000a     r10: 0x00142160     r11: 0x00000001
ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fdfdf4c      lr: 0x35de3ac5      pc: 0x35de3ad0
cpsr: 0x00000010
```

Comment: can you symbolicate the crash report (drag it onto the device log in xcode organizer)?

Comment: A main difference between a developer and an ad-hoc version is that the former is built with debug settings and the latter one with release settings. Have you tried to build with release settings and directly run it from XCode on a device?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seemed to be caused by xcode 4.3 vs xcode 4.2

When we buuld in 4.3 it wont load on all devices but it will for 4.2
Investigating further what could be causing this

Comment: I have seen the same issue with build errors with XCode 4.3 vs 4.2 and would love to figure out why. I was magically able to fix the issue for one of my apps (not all of them though) by ensuring that the app ID was enabled for iCloud support in the provisioning portal. Once I enabled iCloud support, re-generated the provisioning profile, and packaged the app with that profile, the app started working on the ad hoc devices again. Unfortunately that "trick" hasn't worked for my several other apps.